# $stateProvider requests template in templateURL with accept header as application/json which must be text/html

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-routing

when we are actually requesting for a template url . The accept header is always `application/json` instead of `text/html`

I am currently Using nancy for generating both template and api request based on the content request type on accept headers .

Something like this

```
private dynamic Index(dynamic parameters)
{
    Students = NancyContext.Set<Student>().ToList();
    Negotiate.WithView("Index").WithModel(Students);
}
```

which basically when requested with `application/json` returns json . And when requested with `text/html` then it returns the template with model . But since its requesting the template with `application/json` . Its only returning json for the api request and not the template . Any workaround for to change the accept header to text/html instead of `application/json` for template url ?

Comment: Why is this flagged as Angular... the code is not angular code

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat yeah but the code might not be related to angular but that actual problem is related to angular and ui router . So thought people can understand what kind of problem I am going through

Comment: could you add a dump of request/response sequence?

Comment: Joy - did you ever figure out what to change to get this to work? I'm seeing the same issue? Thanks, David

Comment: @DavidManske I have reported this as a bug . Since i was facing the same with nancy with content negotiation . seems like they have taken this as feature request for roadmap for v.0.3.0

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1287

Answer (score 0):

IT was feature which was supposed to be integrated . So it has been integrated into

[#1287](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1287)